# MySQL query string error

Tags: php, mysql

Alright I don't know why this line code isn't working. I have used it on a site before so now I am coping and pasting and I get an error on this site but didn't get one on the last.

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO calendar (group, date, subject, info,) 
   VALUES ('$group', '$date', '$subject', '$info')";
```

^^^^ My query

```
   if(mysql_query($query)){
         echo "Form Successfully Submited!";
   }
```

^^^^ Submitting the query

Like I have said I have used this code  before with no error but now I get a error. The error says 
    Query Submit Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, date, subject, info,) VALUES ('SlowTheTurtle', '0412014', 'asdfasdf', 'a' at line 1

Comment: Get rid of the comma after info

Comment: it seems that you have additional comma on selecting fields, also it's not recommend to use the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: Is there possible an apostrophe in the `$info` variable? If so, not only will it crash this query, but your code is open to SQL injection. Note also that `mysql_*()` is deprecated and should not be used for new code. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group`  is a [`reserved word(s)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You need to wrap them using backticks.

Must be like this..

```
$query = "INSERT INTO calendar (`group`, `date`, `subject`, `info`) 
   VALUES ('$group', '$date', '$subject', '$info')";
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma after the first word 'info', not following by another column name. Could that be it?

Try:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO calendar (group, date, subject, info)
    VALUES ('$group', '$date', '$subject', '$info')";
```

Comment: good eye on the extra comma, but the bigger issue is the `group` as it is a reserved word, as in `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thanks @Sean. Good to know! I guess I've never had to populate a table with a column named 'group' in a MySQL DB before.

Comment: Ricardo, @Sean is right 100% , as you can see the error states .. _right syntax to use near 'group, d_ , so that gives you a hint :)